# Powerpoint keeps starting with windows (And crashing)

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, boot, microsoft-powerpoint

Whenever my pc boots it tries to start powerpoint, which crashes and asks if it should be started in safe mode.

After this wether you click yes or no powerpoint starts. How can I prevent powerpoint from starting with windows I can't find anything in msconfig, the startup manager of CCleaner or the startup folder.

Regards, Xeross

Using Windows XP

Comment: You can't find anything in those locations? Or nothing that seems of consequence? check all the locations mentioned at http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial44.html and keep in mind it could be anything from an installer to a batch file to a ppt file to an ini file with a bad file association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from Microsoft which will give you a more exaustive list of startup files than msconfig. Use the search function to look for `.ppt` as well as `powerpnt.exe`.

Comment: Hmm sounds like it might work